# Jenkins Deployment Takes Long Time to Checkout Code from SVN for New Tags

Tags: svn, deployment, jenkins

Using **Jenkins** as CI for Deployment on the Linux Server. The Deployment is Easy and Convenient.

But the Problem is, Each time if i need to Deploy the build to *Newly* Created *SVN Tags*, The SVN checkout takes Long Time. The Checkout of ***.jar*** files is taking long time.

Is there any way to Skip this part? I mean, Manual Copying of ***.jars***(something like this) will help in overcoming the Deployment Time? or Any other Procedure?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, Jar files should not be version controlled in source control system but instead their source code alone should be version controlled in SVN.

However, if you have it setup the jar files in SVN, then I would suggest you move them to a common folder in SVN like library and then do a checkout only when there is a change to the library folder.

In the Jenkin's job workspace, the libraries can be referred relative to the Job workspace directory / a separate job can be configured to update/ checkout the libraries on a need basis.

This will help reduce the latency of your actual job wasting time in pulling down libraries from SVN.